# ML.NET align multiple time series tables

Tags: time-series, ml.net

I want to view the consumed energy every 5 minutes. I have two Energy counters which generate data with different time stamps.

Counter values from SolarPanel

| DateTime | Counter |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 8:00:01 | 123.0 |
| 2021-01-01 8:01:00 | 123.1 |
| 2021-01-01 8:05:55 | 123.4 |
| 2021-01-01 8:09:02 | 125.3 |
| 2021-01-01 8:11:55 | 126.9 |

Counter values from EnergyProvider

| DateTime | Counter |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 8:01:05 | 423.0 |
| 2021-01-01 8:01:22 | 427.5 |
| 2021-01-01 8:06:55 | 428.6 |
| 2021-01-01 8:09:33 | 431.8 |
| 2021-01-01 8:13:55 | 433.3 |

First, I want to resample the data, so the have same timestamps

Energyprovider (recalculated)

| DateTime | Counter | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 8:05:00 | 123.3441 |  |
| 2021-01-01 8:10:00 | 125.8364 | 2.4923 |

SolarPanel (recalculated)

| DateTime | Counter | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 8:05:00 | 427.7570 |  |
| 2021-01-01 8:10:00 | 431.9546 | 4.1976 |

The energy produced by the Solarpanel between 8:05 en 8:10 is 2.4923 Wh
The energy consumed from the net between 8.05 en 8.10 is 4.1976 Wh

The total energy consumed = 6.69 Wh

Is interpolation possible in ML.NET?
Is there a Diff function available?
Can two tables by joined by DateTime?

I've Googled the whole day find anything usefull, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really a problem for Machine Learning. Perhaps a simple algorithm for measuring timespans and calculating the difference would be more appropriate.

You could put the data into a SQL DB and use a stored procedure, or you could do it directly in your language of choice:

Steps might be:

1. Create Lists (or arrays) of type DateTime and Double for both SolarPanel and EnergyProvider and add your data to them.
2. Create a start DateTime object with the time of when you want the sequence to start.
3. Create a List of DateTime objects using your start datetime and incrementing by by timespans using:

   `DateTime.AddMinutes(5)`
4. Then iterate your SolarPanel and EnergyProvider Lists and find the index of values within consecutive items in the list created in step 3  This can be done something like:

   `for(int i=0; i<myTimeSeqeunce.Length; i++) { TimeSpan varTime = solarPanelDT[i] - myTimeSequence[i]; int intMinutes = (int)varTime.TotalMinutes; }`
5. use `i` to find the relevant values in your solarPanel and EnergyProvider lists and then calculate the difference of the sums of them.
6. Now should have Lists of your desired time sequence and corresponding sums and differences.